# .NET Entity Framework Core version assembly version mismatch

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am trying to walk through the Contoso University tutorial, located here:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro
```

I've gotten through all the steps up to the process of running `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` line.  When I do I get this error:

```
C:\dev\vs\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity>dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Student -dc SchoolContext -udl -outDir Pages\Students --referenceScriptLibraries
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
Running the generator 'razorpage'...
Attempting to compile the application in memory.
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Student'
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:08.32
```

I've made sure that I update my version of EF Core to the latest version: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.0.2`

My NuGet Dependencies show `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.0.2)`.

Here is my project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What do I need to do to get past this error?

Comment: Actually, I think I just figured it out.  I manually changed the referenced `CodeGeneration.Design` and `CodeGeneration.Utils` to `Version 2.0.2` and that seems to have done the trick. I still don't know why `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` determines what version it wants to look for.